# Cannot find element using xpath (Python and selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, element

I try to make some automations using Python+selenium (new to this). Unfortunatelly, inspecting elements of a specific webpage is more than hard. There is no id to use and I try xpath. 
I want to select a drop down list , i inspect this element and I copy the xpath which is 
//*[@id="frmMain:criteria:purchase_criteria_tab"]/div[13]/div[1]/div/button

my code is:

```
    NEXT_BUTTON_XPATH = "//*[@id='frmMain:criteria:purchase_criteria_tab']/div[13]/div[1]/div/button"
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
condition = expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, NEXT_BUTTON_XPATH))
button = wait.until(condition)
button.click()
```

and I cannot get the element
Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
try:
    # for click element element_to_be_clickable condition used
    button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH, "elemnt_xpath"))) 
    button.click()

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: thank you. it returned a new error , Other element would receive the click: <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">...</span>

Comment: edit your question and add the URL which you are trying to scrape.

Comment: it's not a public URL

Comment: the syntax is correct for getting element.try to inspect element by right-clicking and copy XPath of element.

Comment: thats what i do, i already wrote it above, but it returns Other element would receive the click: <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">...</span>

Comment: check the edited answer and what exception you are getting

Comment: thank you you guided me to find the solution. I appreciate your time :)

Comment: Welcome, you can upvote answer so others might help it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the element using the syntax:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='frmMain:criteria:purchase_criteria_tab']/div[13]/div[1]/div/button"))).click()
```

**Note: You have to add the following imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: thank you , i missed last import. syntax is ok now but element is not found :/

Comment: @gplati that is another question, please check your xpath for that and post that as a new question if still not solved